# oracle 11.2.0 - create or replace synonym privilege for a user

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

In oracle 11.2.0 if we grant create synonym to a user , does this mean the use has create or replace synonym privilege or only create synonym privilege?

Comment: Why don't you try it out for yourself?

Comment: Why not try it out yourself? A user can create/replace/drop a synonym with the create synonym privilege.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special system privilege 'grant create or replace' in Oracle RDBMS. When granted the 'create synonym privilege', the user will be able to use both the `CREATE SYNONYM` as well as the `CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM` syntax. Check the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7001.htm#SQLRF01401) for more info.